# How to use a parameterised method as an action method in struts2?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2

I have this method as an action method in struts2

**public String validateUser(User u)**

> What entry should I add in struts.xml file ?

Comment: You can't see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191530/invoke-struts-2-action-method-with-different-arguments

Comment: @user1283689: i am not sure what is your requirement and moreover its the framework contract for method signature

Comment: You can't do it. You can't change the method signature. if you want to be worked need to change framework implementation as well. A simple example. Can you write a main method with changing method signature?

Comment: It's possible in JSF with EL 2.2 though.

Comment: It's been possible with OGNL for ages, but from the view layer, certain features are not allowed from the client for security reasons... hmm... Well a solution springs to mind, I'll post it but don't really like it.

Comment: Never mind I can't think of why the OP would want to do this, if such an interface on the client side is required then using pattern matching could produce the desired effect. It is not really practical to circumvent the standard struts2 way.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Change the question to reflect the use-case and we can tell you how it would be typically done with struts2.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Even though struts2 makes our lives much easier giving us the MVC approach to web programming, HTML will be always be HTML and the only things you can pass as parameters on HTML are good 'ol strings.

You can put it on the Session though. Yet remember sessions are fragile and short-lived